# Prometheus : condition on label value and add other result as information

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

i have a query to perform

```
sum by(proxy, code) (rate(haproxy_server_http_responses_total{code=~"5xx|2xx",proxy="api_backend"}[10m]))
```

the result of this query

```
{code="2xx", proxy="api_backend"} value1
{code="5xx", proxy="api_backend"} value2
```

i want to trigger the alert only when value2 > x and add extra information about value2.(let value2 as it is without condition)

I have trying this code but it is not working

```
sum by(proxy, code) (rate(haproxy_server_http_responses_total{code="5xx",proxy="api_backend"}[10m])) > x or sum by(proxy, code) (rate(haproxy_server_http_responses_total{code="2xx",proxy="api_backend"}[10m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following PromQL query:

```
(
  sum by(proxy)
  (rate(haproxy_server_http_responses_total{code="2xx",proxy="api_backend"}[10m]))
)
and
(
  sum by(proxy)
  (rate(haproxy_server_http_responses_total{code="5xx",proxy="api_backend"}[10m])) > x
)
```

It should return `2xx` response rates for proxies with `5xx` response rates higher than `x`.

How does it work?

- The `by(proxy, code)` is substituted with `by(proxy)` in the query above. This is because Prometheus performs `a op b` query over time series with identical sets of labels at `a` and `b` sides. In the original query the set of labels weren't identical, because they differ by `code` label value. See [matching rules for binary operators in Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).
- The `or` operator is substituted with `and` operator and the `rate(...{code="2xx"}` is put in the front of the query, since `a and b` returns `a` when there is a matching time series with the same set of labels at `b`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) for details about `or` and `and` operators.